# Android scroll view in xml getting unfortunately stopped exception

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I tried to put scroll view here but when I run it it will getting unfortunately stopping exception.

But when I remove scroll view from it the button was not visible on the screen.How to apply scroll view here to get by button visible..

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="511dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Faculty Name:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/faculty_textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#83C9E7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/branch_textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/faculty_textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#83C9E7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year_textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/branch_textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#83C9E7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:text="Year             :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Branch         :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="Select Date:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selected_Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/date_picker_Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/selected_Date"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:src="@drawable/datepicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Go" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It should look like:

[image]

this is my Avtivity:

```
public class SelectionActivity extends Activity {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TextView selected_Date;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.selected_details);

        selected_Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_Date);

//      datePicker.setVisibility(View.GONE); If I put this line I am getting null pointer exception other wise working fine

        // date picker
        setCurrentdateonView();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String faculty = intent.getStringExtra("faculty_name");
        String branch = intent.getStringExtra("branch_name");
        String year = intent.getStringExtra("year_name");

        TextView facultyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_textView4);
        TextView branchTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.branch_textView5);
        TextView yearTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year_textView6);

        facultyTextView.setText(faculty);
        branchTextView.setText(branch);
        yearTextView.setText(year);

        findViewById(R.id.date_picker_Image).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerLisner, year, month, day);

        }
        return null;
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerLisner = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int Selectyear, int Selectmonth, int Selectday) {
            year = Selectyear;
            month = Selectmonth;
            day = Selectday;
            selected_Date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(Selectmonth + 1).append("-").append(Selectday).append("-")
                    .append(Selectyear).append(""));
            datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);
        }
    };
    private void setCurrentdateonView() {

        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        selected_Date.setText(new StringBuffer().append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                .append(""));
        datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);
    }

}
```

Here I don't want to show date picker when launching the activity.How?

LOG:

```
01-07 20:31:22.830: W/Choreographer(30706): Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
01-07 20:31:22.880: I/brcm-gr(30706): [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933
01-07 20:31:22.970: D/AbsListView(30706): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-07 20:31:23.010: D/AndroidRuntime(30706): Shutting down VM
01-07 20:31:23.010: W/dalvikvm(30706): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41401930)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.geeklabs.studentattendance/com.geeklabs.studentattendance.activity.SelectionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at com.geeklabs.studentattendance.activity.SelectionActivity.onCreate(SelectionActivity.java:34)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
01-07 20:31:23.010: E/AndroidRuntime(30706):    ... 11 more
```

How to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I solved this issue

Just by inserting this line before `datePicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);` this line

> datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

Comment: Even though the question is in this case answerable, always include exception details such as stacktrace from logcat in questions. Also, reading the exception text yourself would have pointed you directly to the solution.

Comment: post the exception stacktrace and for further comments join the chat

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Quoting docs

ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

So put all your views in `LinearLayout` and make LinearLayout a child of ScrollView.

There might be other mistakes as well in which case you should post the stacktrace

```
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Faculty Name:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/faculty_textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#83C9E7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/branch_textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/faculty_textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#83C9E7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year_textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/branch_textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#83C9E7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:text="Select Date:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:text="Go" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Branch         :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/faculty_textView4"
            android:text="Year             :"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Snaps

I tried it on Kikat. So you get the new DatePicker look.(Ignore it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am unable to get my view clearly.

Comment: @shylendra can you be more specific and also post the stacktracw

Comment: @shylendra what you mean by unable to get view clearly. Does it crash?

Comment: @shylendra that is because orientation of LinearLayout is vertical. So the views are one below the other. the order does not change. Remove the attributes of relative layout like `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"`.

Comment: I removed all attributes and like you mentioned,Now getting view clearly but I want one text view is right of another.How can i?

Comment: Then you should use RelativeLayout for those textviews only. Which one do you want to place  right relative to other??

Comment: I want to get faculty,year and branch text views to right side of Text view 1 2 and 3 respectively..

Comment: @shylendra can you post a snap shot of how it should look. Whether you want them at the bottom or top.

Comment: Ok sure. i'll post it wait few sec's

Comment: @shylendra no need i understaood

Comment: See above i edited(added screen shot) in my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44619/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-shylendra)

Comment: Every thing working fine with UI but I am unable to hide that date picker on opening the activity. I want to show that date picker after click on a button but it showing directly.If I tried to hide it getting null pointer exception.

Comment: @shylendra that is a different issue. you can set the visibility of the view as INVISIBLE in xml and make it VISIBLE on button click.

Comment: Let we discuss on chat please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44619/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-shylendra

Comment: @shylendra no view with id `date_picker_Image` in your xml. secondly you are not using dialog fragment which i recommend.

Comment: 1. post stacktrace without which no further help. 2. join the chat too many comments leading to discussion.

Comment: I solved my issue. Just I am calling date picker before getting its id from layout.I solved it working fine now.Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` can have only 1 child. So place all the `TextViews` in a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 1):

***ScrollView*** is view in which you can add only one View. And If you are trying to set another view then it display the error "***ScrollView can host only one child view***".

So there is a better way to take one ***Vertical*** ***Linear Layout*** and put all your TextViews insides it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A scrollview can only have one child.
Put all the views into a Vertical LinearLayout and it should work...